# Modulus of Analytic Function is Bounded Above

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I have the following problem that I am stuck on:

> Let $f$ be analytic in $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\::\:|z|<1\}$ and suppose that $|f(z)|<M$ for all $z\in D$.
>
> (a) If $f(z_{k})=0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$, show that $$|f(z)|\leq M\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{|z-z_{k}|}{|1-\bar{z}_{k}z|}$$ for $|z|<1$.
>
> (b) If $f(z_{k})=0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$, each $z_{k}\neq 0$, and $f(0)=Me^{i\alpha}(z_{1}z_{2}\cdots z_{n})$, find a formula for $f$.

I honestly have no idea of where to begin with this problem. I think that Schwarz's Lemma may be needed somewhere? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: to be honest, I think Alexandre's solution is more than detailed enough.

Comment: @mathworker21 I understand how his solution implies part (a). Yet part (b) I find confusing, and I'm not sure how his solution implies it.

Answer (score 2):

Function $$g_k(z)=\frac{z-z_k}{1-z\overline{z_k}}$$ has the following properties:
a) it has a simple zero at $z_k$, and no other zeros, b) it is analytic in $|z|\leq 1$, and c)
$|g_k(z)|=1$ for $|z|=1$. 
Consider the ratio
$$G(z)=\frac{f(z)}{\prod_{k=1}^n g_k(z)} $$
It is analytic (the poles at $z_k$ are removable) and satisfies $|G(z)|\leq M$
for $|z|=1$. By the Maximum Principle $|G(z)|\leq M$ in the unit disk, and this is
your inequality.

For b), Maximum Principle says that this  inequality is everywhere strict, or everywhere equality. If for example
$|G(0)|=M$ then $f=Me^{i\theta}\prod g_k$.

Comment: How would you go about finding the formula for $f$?

Comment: to be honest, I think Alexandre's solution is more than detailed enough.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, but where does the $e^{i\theta}$ come from?

Comment: Is it because we get $|f(z)|=M|g_1\cdots g_n|$?

Comment: @ponchan $G$ is analytic and thus an open mapping unless it's constant. Since $G$ attains its maximum at the origin, it must therefore be constant (if $G$ were an open map, then, for an open neighborhood $U$ around $0$, $G(U)$ would have to be open and thus $|G(U)|$ would have some values greater than $M$ -- this is basic topology).

Comment: @mathworker21 My specific question is where does the $e^{i\theta}$ come from?

Comment: @ponchan $G$ is constant. Say $G(z) = z_0$ for all $z$. We know $|G(0)| = M$. Therefore $z_0 = Me^{i\theta}$ for some $\theta$.